# How to pop all elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, data-structures

```
var arr = [0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let item = arr.pop()
    console.log(item)
}
//Returns 6, 5, 5, 4, 3
```

I have no idea why this is returning only the numbers given instead of every number in the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because `arr.length` is changing while you loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) returns:

> The removed element from the array; `undefined` if the array is empty.

So technically on each iteration the code removes the last element from the array which changes the `.length` property.

Probably a good representation what happens with the extended index from the loop:

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let item = arr.pop()
    console.log({i, item, length: arr.length});
}
```

All together `for` loop was running the block five times which represents the last five elements from your array if you read the array from the back. That's why you have `6,5,5,4,3` as an output.

I hope this clarifies!

Comment: Might be helpful to also log the `arr.length` to better demonstrate the issue. `console.log({i, item, "arr.length": arr.length})`. Otherwise this demonstrates the problem pretty good.

Comment: You can do that with for loop, you need just to reverse iteration, checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you change `for` to `while` loop?
You would then console log all items

```js
while(arr.length) {
    let item = arr.pop()
    console.log(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse your iteration, becuase .pop method removes the last item so when iterating from 0 to last item you will not find all of them :)

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6];

for(let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    let item = arr.pop()
    console.log(item)
}
```